# How long would fruit trees take to mature if we induce early cropping?

Tags: fruit-trees, propagation, apples

For standard sized apple trees, it can take up to eight years for them to start producing. One common solution is to graft them onto a dwarfing rootstocks which makes them mature in just a few years.

Some of the early cropping techniques done in own-root fruit trees include:
Tying down 1 and 2 year old branches to the horizontal
Summer pruning while avoiding winter pruning
Withholding nitrogen
Root pruning
https://www.cooltemperate.co.uk/own-root-project/

The techniques don't seem very common, and it sounded too good to be true for seed grown standard sized apples to bear fruits in only a few years. How long should we expect to wait until we see fruits if we followed the techniques?

Comment: Seed grown apple trees? What seed did you use (as in where did you get it from)?

Comment: I'm talking about apples from supermarkets

Comment: Thanks... if you grow an apple tree from a seed in an apple you've bought, there's no way of knowing what kind of apple will grow - it maybe a 50 foot giant with thorns that finally, after years, produces very small, sour apples for instance. Or it might be a smaller tree with reasonable apples on it - because of this unpredictability, it is hard/impossible to answer your actual question

Comment: Post a picture of your apple tree